# How do I make a file field required using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to make a form with an attachment field(file). I want to validate this field. I know how to do this with PHP, but i'd much rather use javascript to do it. Does anyone know a way to do this? I searched around the internet but couldn't find a solution..

This is my file field:

```
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" accept="image/*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" accept="image/*" required />
```

And also check with JS:

```
if ( $('#image').is(':empty') ) {
  // empty
}
```

Comment: since the required attribute doesn't work in older browsers it isn't a reliable solution. The jquery one will probably work! so thanks.

Comment: `required` can be treated as an extra check.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" accept="image/*" />
```

you can check if is valid, like this:

```
var file = $('#image').val();
if (file === '') {
      // not valid      
      alert('File is not valid');
}
```